# Yahoo Weather API Not Being Able To Search Through Variables

Tags: api, discord, yql, discord.js, yahoo-weather-api

Alright, so this sounds like a weird question. I am using yahoo weather API, and discord.js to make a weather command. I use YQL and WOIED to try to have someone enter in their place they want to search up. Here is the variable search:

```
const query = new YQL(`SELECT * FROM weather.forecast WHERE woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places(1) WHERE text= ${place})`)
```

When I use the variable input though, it does not work, and will give me this error:

```
Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
```

Now, when I manually input the place **I** want to see, it works. Here is what I mean:

```
const query = new YQL(`SELECT * FROM weather.forecast WHERE woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places(1) WHERE text= "Broomfield, Co")`)
```

*Note that I have my main emphasis on the `WHERE text =` portion of each search query*

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the variable you are inserting has double quotes as part of the string, you are going to have to insert them yourself in the format string. For example:

```
const query = new YQL(`SELECT * FROM weather.forecast WHERE woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places(1) WHERE text= "${place}")`)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong with the place variable.  You could try doing

```
console.log(`place: ${place}`);
```

before you initialize your query to see what's wrong with it. It could be improperly formatted (e.g. "Broomfield, Colorado"), or it could contain nothing at all.